# Intellij IDEA terminal running oh-my-zsh not correctly mapping these specific keys

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, keymapping

Environment:
MacOS
Intellij IDEA Terminal
oh-my-zsh

While trying to execute a backwards or forwards word jump using the `alt-<back arrow>` or `alt-<front arrow>` combination, I get `OD` or `OC`  instead. I've tried:

[A picture of my settings in IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qm0W.png)

- "shell integration" in idea terminal settings on and off. This seems to only remove the `O` from the output.
- "Override IDE shortcuts", as well as various others on this screen
- sourcing a new .inputrc to include the jumping keystrokes. this doesn't really make sense, however since **if I switch to bash the jumping motion works**.

Additional notes:

- `alt-<backspace>` works

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198058

Comment: thanks for the link y.bedrov what worked for me was placing 

```bindkey "\e\eOC" forward-word
bindkey "\e\eOD" backward-word```

at the end of my .zshrc